# Cat locked in apartment basement

Tags: cats, legal

I recently moved into a new apartment, which does allow cats. Today, I heard meowing coming from the laundry room in the basement, and thinking it was a stray, went to leave it food and water before calling a shelter. However, the cat is locked inside of a mesh-lined area meant for resident storage, with blankets draped around it and the door locked, and there is litter, food, and water already inside.

Since these areas are for resident rental only, it's got to be one of our neighbor's cats, but it's very cold and dark down there and he is quite obviously not in a large enough space. We're considering talking to the rental office, a shelter, or animal control, but we're not sure who'd be best able to help. It's even a possibility they're keeping a stray there for a few days until they can get him to a shelter, but...

For reference, I live in Maryland.

What is the best course of action?

Comment: Yeah, I actually just ran into the person and she says she's sheltering him from the cold until she can get him to the vet, so I suppose that's the best way it can turn out. Thanks!